# How to acess matrix's elements and pass matrix as function argument?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

My program is supposed to simulate a Bingo game. It receives as input a 5X5 matrix (the Bingo card), the number of elements(which are integers) it should verify whether they are on the card and the series of elements, one by one. The goal is to verify whether or not each element is in the matrix: if affirmative, the program should replace the corresponding element by "XX". The program should continuously proceed in the forementioned fashion until all elements are verified. If all the elements of any row, column or either diagonals are replaced by "XX", the program is to print the final scenario (the final stage of the matrix), with the correct elements replaced by "XX" and the word BINGO!, and just the final scenario otherwise.
 The first line of the matrix contains the letters B I N G O, thus identifying each matrix's column by its corresponding label letter, "B" for the first, "I" for the second, and so on, in a way that the input should be on the form:
label_letter-XY, where X and Y represent the numerals.
I've already managed to correctly print the Bingo card, but I'm still not able to iterate over the matrix's lines and columns, verify whether of not the candidate numbers are in

### those columns, and replace them by "XX". I'm not actually sure what my program is actually doing, since it's only printing the original bingo card, which makes me conclude that the I'm not correctly accessing the matrix. If anyone could give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong, I'll be extremely grateful!

```
m=5             #lines
n=5             #columns/rows
mat=[]
data=[]
for i in range(m):
col=input().split() 
    mat.append(col)
num=int(input())
blank=''
def printbingocard(mat):
    print("+", end=blank)
    print((16)*"-" + "+")
print("| ", end=blank)
print("B  ", end=blank)
print("I  ", end=blank)
print("N  ", end=blank)
print("G  ", end=blank)
print("O  ", end=blank)
print("|")
print("+" + (16)*"=" + "+")
for i in range(m):
    print("| ", end=blank)
    for j in range(n):    
        print(mat[i][j] + " ", end='')
    print("|")
print("+" + (16)*"-" + "+")
printbingocard(mat)
for i in range(num):        
    input=str(input()).split("-")
    input_data.append(input)     

    for j in range(n): 
        if input_data[i][0]=="B":
            if mat[0][j]==input_data[i][1]:  
                mat[0][j]="XX"
                printbingocard(mat)
        if input_data[i][0]=="I":
            if mat[1][j]==input_data[i][1]:
                mat[1][j]="XX"
                printbingocard(mat)
        if input_data[i][0]=="N":
            if mat[2][j]==input_data[i][1]:
                mat[2][j]="XX"
                printbingocard(mat)
        if input_data[i][0]=="G":
            if mat[3][j]==input_data[i][1]:
                mat[3][j]="XX"
                printbingocard(mat)
        if input_data[i][0]=="O":
            if mat[4][j]==input_data[i][1]:
                mat[4][j]="XX"
                printbingocard(mat)
for i in range(m):       
    for j in range(n):
        if mat[i][j]== "XX":
            bol=True
        else:
            bol=False
            break
for j in range(n):       
    for i in range(m):
        if mat[i][j]== "XX":
            bol=True
        else:
            bol=False
            break
printbingocard(mat)
if bol==True:
    print("BINGO!")   
for j in range(n):       
    for i in range(m):
        if mat[j][j]=="XX" or mat[i][i]=="XX": 
            bol=True
        else:
            bol=False
            break
printbingocard(mat)
if bol==True:
    print("BINGO!")
for j in range(4,n,-1):          
    for i in range(1,m,1):      
        if mat[i][j]=="XX":
            bol=True
        else:
            bol=False
            break
printbingocard(mat)
if bol==True:
    print("BINGO!")
```

Comment: Can you please only post the relevent code as part of an [VMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if you're going to share your code, use English variable names

Comment: is the part where you try to access the matrix the commented part ? If it were possible to uncomment the actual code you need to work but add English comments to understand what this part is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

My take on it, I use atom text editor for my python programming so I don't have `input()` functions so I had to randomize my bingo array

```
import random
import numpy as np

m=5             #lines
n=5             #columns/rows
mat=[]
bingo_numbers = np.linspace(1,n*m,n*m,dtype=int)
remaining_numbers = bingo_numbers # I need this later on to know what numbers are left
random.shuffle(bingo_numbers)
print(bingo_numbers)
completed_lines = 0

for i in range(m):
    col=bingo_numbers[i*5:(i+1)*5]
    mat.append(list(col))

def imprimecartela(mat, completed_lines):  # Function to print the bingo card
    print("+", end=branco)
    print((16)*"-" + "+")
    print("| ", end=branco)
    if (completed_lines == 0):
        print(5*"_  ", end=branco)
    elif(completed_lines == 1):
        print("B  ", end=branco)
        print(4*"_  ", end=branco)
    elif(completed_lines == 2):
        print("B  ", end=branco)
        print("I  ", end=branco)
        print(3*"_  ", end=branco)
    elif(completed_lines == 3):
        print("B  ", end=branco)
        print("I  ", end=branco)
        print("N  ", end=branco)
        print(2*"_  ", end=branco)
    elif(completed_lines == 4):
        print("B  ", end=branco)
        print("I  ", end=branco)
        print("N  ", end=branco)
        print("G  ", end=branco)
        print("_  ", end=branco)
    else:
        print("B  ", end=branco)
        print("I  ", end=branco)
        print("N  ", end=branco)
        print("G  ", end=branco)
        print("O  ", end=branco)
    print("|")
    print("+" + (16)*"=" + "+")
    for i in range(m):
        print("| ", end=branco)
        for j in range(n):
            if mat[i][j] != 0:  # Check values of <mat>: if non zero print number with 2 digits, if zero print 'XX'
                print(str(mat[i][j]).zfill(2) + " ", end='')
            else:
                print("XX" + " ", end='')
        print("|")
    print("+" + (16)*"-" + "+")

def check_completed_lines(mat):
    completed_lines = 0
    for i in range(m):
        temp = [x[i] for x in mat]
        if (temp == [0,0,0,0,0]):
            completed_lines += 1
    for x in mat:
        if x==[0,0,0,0,0]:
            completed_lines += 1
    if (mat[0][0] == 0 and mat[1][1] == 0 and mat[2][2] == 0 and mat[3][3] == 0 and mat[4][4] == 0):
        completed_lines += 1
    if (mat[0][4] == 0 and mat[1][3] == 0 and mat[2][2] == 0 and mat[3][1] == 0 and mat[4][0] == 0):
        completed_lines += 1
    return completed_lines

imprimecartela(mat,completed_lines)

while (len(remaining_numbers) != 0): # Looping through turns  
    call_number = random.choice(remaining_numbers) # <-- Next number
    print("next number is : ", call_number)
    remaining_numbers = np.delete(remaining_numbers, np.where(remaining_numbers==call_number)) # Remove the number so it doesn't occur again
    for i in mat:
        if call_number in i:
            i[i.index(call_number)] = 0  # Change the value current round number to 0 in <mat>
    completed_lines = check_completed_lines(mat) # This function checks rows and columns and diagonals for completeness, every completed line will add a letter to "BINGO" on the card
    imprimecartela(mat, completed_lines)
    if completed_lines == 5:
        break    # When 5 lines are completed, you win, break
```

I added comments inside the code to explain the process, but basically you don't need to change the matrix to include `'XX'` just change the value to `0` since zero is already not a bingo number and use your print function to print `'XX'` if the value is `0`. Cheers.